# Output multiple rows in json in Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, json, zend-framework

I've searched and can't find an answer to my question.

I have the following code which is to loop through an array and then fetch back results for the different $id's. 
The output when using `echo json_encode($row);` returns all results but the zend layout displays. 
However when using `$this->_helper->json($row,true);` the layout doesn't display but only one result returns.

How can I return more than one result?

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public function testAction()

{



    //Get latest revision from database and loop through $id's
    $id = array('308', '307', '306');

    //Connect to database

    foreach($id as $lId) {

        $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();


        $select = $db->select('')
            ->from('LinktagRevisions')
            ->where('linktagId = ?', $lId)
            ->order('updated DESC')
            ->limit(1);

        $stmt = $select->query();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {


            $this->_helper->json($row,true);
    //Encode as json and echo result
           // echo json_encode($row);
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this:

```
$result = array();
foreach($id as $lId) {
    ....
    $stmt = $select->query();
    $result[$lId] = $stmt->fetchAll();

}
$this->_helper->json($result,true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that still only seems to return one result.

Comment: Sorry, I forget the 1rst loop. I update the answer. And I add Id index

Comment: You're welcome! Thank's for your return. :) Good Luck.